# Java NIO: Writing File Header - Using SeekableByteChannel

Tags: java, nio

I am manually serializing data objects to a file, using a ByteBuffer and its operations such as `putInteger()`, `putDouble()` etc.

One of the fields I'd like to write-out is a String. For the sake of example, let's say this contains a currency. Each currency has a three-letter ISO currency code, e.g. GBP for British Pounds Sterling.

Assuming each object I'm serializing just has a double and a currency; you could consider the serialized data to look something like:

```
100.00|GBP
200.00|USD
300.00|EUR
```

Obviously in reality I'm not delimiting the data (the pipe between fields, nor the line feeds), it's stored in binary - just using the above as an illustration.

Encoding the currency with each entry is a bit inefficient, as I keep storing the same three-characters. Instead, I'd like to have a header - which stores a mapping for currencies. The file would look something like:

```
100
GBP
USD
EUR
~~~
~~~
100.00|1
200.00|2
300.00|3
```

The first 2 bytes in the file is a short, filled with the decimal value 100. This informs me that there are 100 spaces for currencies in the file. Following this, there are 3-byte chunks which are the currencies in order (ASCII-only characters).

When I read the file back in, all I have to do is build up a 100-element array with the currency codes, and I can cheaply / efficiently look up the relevant currency for each line.

Reading the file back-in seems simple. But I'm interested to hear thoughts on writing-out the data.

I don't know all the currencies up-front, and I'm actually supporting any three-character code - even if it's invalid. Thus I have to build-up the table converting currencies to indexes on-the-fly.

I am intending on using a SeekableByteChannel to address my file, and seeking back to the header every time I find a new currency I've not indexed before.

This has obvious I/O overhead of moving round the file. But, I am expecting to see all the different currencies within the first few data objects written. So it'll probably only seek for the first few seconds of execution, and then not have to perform an additional seek for hours.

The alternative is to wait for the stream of data to finish, and then write the header once. However, if my application crashes and I haven't written-out the header, the data in the file cannot be recovered back to its original content.

Seeking seems like the right thing to do, but I've not attempted it before - and was hoping to hear horror-stories up-front, rather than through trial/error on my end.

Comment: Have you considered using an embedded database? Otherwise it looks for me like you are re-inventing the wheel like a database with transactions.

Comment: @Robert The data I am storing needs to be indexed for very fast access. Given my data is fixed-width I can locate the nth element exceptionally quickly, by finding the start of the data payload, and then seeking to n * object-size-in-bytes. I will be storing tens-of-millions of records, and the input rate is very "bursty" - at certain times of day I can receive hundreds of thousands of records a second. I am looking for something that is very fast, I don't necessarily need something which has all the features of an SQL-like embedded DB. products like Derby / HSQLDB are just too slow.

Comment: OK, if you want to code an optimized version on your own use two files, one for currencies and one for the data, then you don't have to think of offsets...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you say that you do not want to limit the number of currency codes which implies that you don’t know how much space you have to reserve for the header. Seeking in a plain local file might be cheap if not performed too often, but shifting the entire file contents to reserve more room for the header is **big**.

The other question is how you define efficiency. If you don’t limit the number of currency codes you have to be aware of the case that a single byte is not sufficient for your index so you need either a dynamic possibly-multi-byte encoding which is more complicated to parse or a fixed multi-byte encoding which ends up taking the same number of bytes as the currency code itself.

So if not space-efficiency for the typical case is more important to you than decoding efficiency you can use the fact that these codes are all made up of ASCII characters only. So you can encode each currency code in three bytes and if you accept one padding byte you can use a single `putInt`/`getInt` for storing/retrieving a currency code without the need for any header lookup.

I don’t believe that optimizing these codes further would improve you storage significantly. The table does not consist of currency codes only. It’s very likely the other data will take much more space.

Comment: I didn't say I don't want to limit the number of currency codes :-) I am willing to declare this up-front, probably in config. In the example above, I'd reserve enough spaces for 100 currencies. If I attempted to put in the 101st currency, I'd throw an exception.... hence I would never want to shift the contents of the file to make way for a larger header.

Comment: Currency codes are on example, there are other examples where the number of characters will be a lot longer, say 10. I am considering assuming that the encoded index number (1,2,3...) will be a short and not a byte. This will give me sufficient indexes for all my use cases.

Comment: I highlight your statement `Seeking in a plain local file might be cheap if not performed too often`. Given the limitations I am willing to make (as per above comments) it sounds like you think it's a reasonable approach?

Comment: Writing the header once at the end is no problem; writing it one every first occurrence might be too much if you have up to 100 codes and want to expand this strategy to other value types as well. It’s always about what the maximum number is. I would write at the end only and not care about whether the file header is usable when the writing is aborted by a crash— the file will be incomplete and very likely in an inconsistent state anyway. So it’s the opposite— I would prefer having no header as a good indicator that the file is incomplete.